# Pandas: Merge on 2 different keys with same value

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes below:

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame([[3,"here",34]],columns = ["comp_id","mail","mean"])
dfB = pd.DataFrame([[23,3,"there"]], columns = ["alt","name_id","serv"])
```

dfA

```
        comp_id  mail  mean
   0          3 "here"   34
```

dfB

```
          alt  name_id   serv
   0       23        3  "there"
```

I want to join both data frames on comp_id = name_id

Output:

```
        mail  mean   alt     serv
 0     "here"   34    23   "there"
```

The output should not include comp_id or name_id.

*Any suggestions on how I can do this?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use merge after setting index for first data frame and drop column from second data frame

```
dfA = dfA.set_index('comp_id')
res = dfA.merge(dfB,left_index=True,right_on='name_id').drop('name_id',axis=1)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `merge` with `left_on` and `right_on`:

```
pd.merge(dfA,dfB,left_on="comp_id", right_on = "name_id", how="inner")
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I still see comp_id and name_id in the output. The output should exclude those keys

Comment: @swapnil123, you can just select the column of interest after merge ``pd.merge(..)[columns]``

Answer (score 1):

Drop you join keys after the merge:

```
dfA.merge(dfB, left_on='comp_id', right_on='name_id').drop(['comp_id','name_id'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   mail  mean  alt   serv
0  here    34   23  there
```